# form submission error in html

Tags: php, html, form-submit

My html page is

```
<html>
    <head>

    </head>
    <body>
        <form name="uploadform" id="uploadform" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data"  action="ProfileBiodataUpload.php">


            <div>     <P3>Upload Biodata</P3></div>
            <div><input type="file" name="fileupload" id="fileupload"/></div>

            <div> <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Upload"/> </div>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

ProfilebiodataUpload.php page is

```
<?php
session_start();
if (isset($_POST['fileupload'])) {
    echo "filename set";
} else {
    echo 'filename not set';
}
?>
```

but here i am getting filename not set error when i am upload with file type.
how to solve this.?thanks in advance

Comment: `if (isset($_FILES['fileupload']))` not `$_POST` - take your pick of answers below; the right ones anyway ;)

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `$_POST['fileupload']`. You have to use `$_FILES['fileupload']`

```
if (isset($_FILES['fileupload'])) {
    echo "filename set";
} else {
    echo 'filename not set';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [$_FILES](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php)

```
$_FILES
```

Insted of

```
$_POST
```

Complete code:

```
if (isset($_FILES['fileupload'])) {
    echo "filename set";
} else {
    echo 'filename not set';
}
```